# Can I use butter in cookies the same if recipe calls for margarine

Tags: butter

Can I use butter in a molasses cookie recipe instead of margarine
I

Comment: It looks like you haven't finished writing. Was there supposed to be something after last "I"?

Answer (score 4):

Definitely yes, and they will probably taste better. 1:1 substitution.

Comment: To me, margarine recipes seem to come from time period when the market tried to convince us they were so much healthier than butter.  I even have some old family recipes that called specifically for oleo.  Agree completely, should work fine and taste better.

Comment: @ Barb, Butter will make the cookies spread out more during baking, so they will turn out flatter. You may have to give more space between them to allow for that.